# GKPeerPickerController throwing exception "expected expression"

Tags: ios, expression, alloc, gkpeerpickercontroller

I have written this little piece of code:

> GKPeerPickerController *picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];

but even after restarting my Mac XCode is telling me: "expected expression"!
Anyone having any idea solving this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are creating picker object in switch case. Put your code in curly braces.

```
case k:
{
     GKPeerPickerController *picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
     //your code
}
```